# Yii user migration issues

Tags: yii, yii-modules

i am new to yii and i need to install yii user module i am stuck at the migration command :

```
Run command: yiic migrate --migrationPath=user.migrations
```

I searched for help and i found this command :

```
yiic migrate --migrationPath=application.modules.user.migrations
```

I am using this yiic.php : .../protected/yiic.php

Error is :

```
exception 'CException' with message 'Property "CConsoleApplication.log" is not defined.' in /srv/data/var/php/www/yii-1.1.15.022a51/framework/base/CComponent.php:173
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /srv/data/var/php/www/yii-1.1.15.022a51/framework/base/CModule.php(513): CComponent->__set('log', Array)
#1 /srv/data/var/php/www/yii-1.1.15.022a51/framework/base/CApplication.php(161): CModule->configure(Array)
#2 /srv/data/var/php/www/yii-1.1.15.022a51/framework/YiiBase.php(125): CApplication->__construct('/srv/data/web/v...')
#3 /srv/data/var/php/www/yii-1.1.15.022a51/framework/YiiBase.php(113): YiiBase::createApplication('CConsoleApplica...', '/srv/data/web/v...')
#4 /srv/data/var/php/www/yii-1.1.15.022a51/framework/yiic.php(23): YiiBase::createConsoleApplication('/srv/data/web/v...')
#5 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.myWebsite.com/htdocs/protected/yiic.php(7): require_once('/srv/data/var/p...')
#6 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.myWebsite.com/htdocs/protected/yiic(4): require_once('/srv/data/web/v...')
#7 {main}hosting-user@me:~/web/vhosts/www.myWebsite.com/htdocs/protected$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your console application has not `log` component.

Try to add this code in your `console.php` config in `components` array:

```
'components'=>array(
...
    'log'=>array(
       'class'=>'CLogRouter',
       'routes'=>array(
          array(
             'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
             'levels'=>'error, warning',
          ),
       ),
    ),
...
),
```